# Converting a bunch or SRA files using fastq-dump

Tags: fastq, ncbi

I have recently downloaded a bunch of sra files. and i like to convert them to fastq paired reads. It works by doing this :

```
./fastq-dump --split-files /Users/medsmit/ncbi/public/sra/SRR3501908.sra
```

But I need a way to convert them all together.

I was trying this

```
for i in  `ls /Users/medsmit/ncbi/public/sra/*.sra' ; do ./fastq-dump -- split-files $f; done
```

But definitely doing some silly mistake as its not working. Can anyone please help me? Thank you,
Suparna

Answer (score 0):

Probably, just changing $f by $i... typo:

```
for i in /Users/medsmit/ncbi/public/sra/*.sra
do
    ./fastq-dump -- split-files $i
done
```